# android: default language set to asian

Tags: android

why is the default language set in my android emulator some asian language?
where can i set the keyboard to english?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the default language of Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755460/how-to-change-the-default-language-of-android-emulator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Menu -> Settings -> Language&Keyboard

Comment: This setting no longer exists in the latest version of Android Studio (4.1.1)