# How to change the default language of Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, locale

How to change the language of the Emulator? By default I am getting Chinese while filling a form.
Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573991/android-default-language-set-to-asian

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are few possible solutions to change the device language.

1. Open menu -> Setting -> Language & Keyboard -> Select Locale. Set any locale from this. It depends on android os version and on device manufacturer.
2. Emulator contains app called "Custom Locale". using that app also you can change the locale of your emulator. I didn't check all type of emulator running on different types of CPU and android version so its not gerrently that this app is present in the emulator.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the intel emulator only comes with english, thus switching language is not supported.

Comment: I am trying to choose Swedish but I can't read some of the languages there.

Comment: there will be "Custom locale" in menu of the simulator. There you go!

Comment: have no "languages.." in settings sdk 4.4

Comment: For android 5.1.1 it is:  
Settings->language and input->android(or whatever) keyboard->languages->set any languages you want here.  
In order to switch languages slide the space bar on your keyboard

Comment: What do you mean by open menu? whose menu are you talking about? please be specific.

Answer (score 39):

For the new simulators, just your new language in

Settings -> System -> Languages & Input,

then `re-order your desired device locale at the top of the languages list` *this is the key!*

It will automatically switch UI for RLT/LTR, and change system locale.

[image: change language]

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer for a recent (spring 2019) version of Android Studio for Windows.

Comment: Which Settings? Is this in the emulator, Android Studio, or for the OS?

Comment: No such option in the latest version of Android Studio (4.1.1).

Comment: It is not in the Studio, it is in the Android Emulator.

Comment: Still valid as of 2023 with a pixel 6 simulator.

Answer (score 14):

It depends form the version emulator.

On Android 4.0: Home -> Central Menu -> Custom Locale

[image: Custom locale selection screen]

Answer (score 10):

Use this to set locale programmatically:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
config.locale = locale;
```

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: @PeteAlvin Java

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Japanese and other input methods from being activated entirely via Settings -→ Keyboard -→ untick the box next to each IME.