# Change Locale for Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I want to test number formatting and translations by simulating different locales in the emulator.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755460/how-to-change-the-default-language-of-android-emulator) seems to have a clear answers on how to change settings in the emulator, but I cannot for the life of me find the language settings.

[image: Emulator Settings Image]

I'm new to Android Studio, so please forgive this simple question that I'm somehow missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You change the locale in an emulator the same way that you do in a device, via the Settings app.

The exact spot in Settings varies by Android version. On 9.0, it is in Settings > System > "Languages & input".

Comment: OK thanks!  The part I was missing was how to get to that Settings app within the emulator.  For other Android noobs like me, in my case it was a "swipe up" from the bottom of the device to see all the apps on the emulator.

Comment: @Ben: That too varies by OS version, and sometimes by settings within the OS version. You can have emulators for pretty much any Android version that has existed (29 and counting).

Comment: You may have to enter App Languages and confirm that the language for the app you are working on is using the system default and not hard coded English (United States) for some reason.